# Friends Nearby with notifications

Tags: java, android, firebase-notifications, geofire

I would like to implement for a case study, a small app that sends a notification to all users within a certain range of the device. what is the right way to implement it with firebase? I thought of GeoFire and I think we need to constantly update the position. Better to do it with a service? How do I send notifications? someone can enlighten me on the best practices to give me a starting point

Comment: If you want to do it via a central server, obviously the server needs to know where all the users are, so I don't understand how you'd expect it to work without "constantly updating the position". Obviously you can drop the update frequency for the appropriate drop in accuracy...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect nearby android devices using the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705088/how-to-detect-nearby-android-devices-using-the-same-app)

Comment: I want to implement it with firebase but I don't understand how to send the notification to the corresponding devices, do I have to implement something specific or does firebase provide me with something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set up a `geoFire.queryAtLocation` to be notified of nearby users' movement in and out of area. The query will continue to fire callbacks at you asynchronously; you do not need to issue the query more than once. `onKeyEntered`, `onKeyExited` and `onGeoQueryError` would be events of interest to you.
- Use `geoQuery.setCenter` repeatedly to update the search criteria to your location, and use `geoFire.setLocation` repeatedly to notify all other nearby clients about where you are.

Comment: and for send location to nearby device? what is the better method? firebase provide me something or need have a service persistent.. and add a field for notification

Comment: Define "notification". Without doing anything beyond what I described above, the client will be notified by a callback when other clients move in and out of radius. If you mean "notification" as some UI popping out on your phone, FireBase has nothing to do with that, you should code it yourself. If you mean text of notification, you can pass it along and use the appropriate `Data` events.